# Allow access to a share on a workgroup using a user which is a part of a domain

Tags: active-directory, vpn, domain, workgroup

There are 2 networks. Network A, which is domain controlled, and Network B, which is a small workgroup. A user from Network A accesses Network B using VPN (Network B is Checkpoint 600, office mode, Windows L2TP).
When a file or a folder is shared with "everyone"  allowed to read, change, etc everything is fine, but I just don't understand how to allow a file/folder on a certain computer, in the local workgroup be accessed from the user in the remote domain.
I`m sorry if I sound confused, or uneducated, this is all very true! our "computer guy" bailed on us for various reason, and I a (very) temp replacement. I will be very glad and thankful if u could help me (and even if not..) thanks.

Comment: The domain user needs to provide local credentials (non-domain) when connecting to the workgroup computer's share.  The local credentials are defined on the workgroup computer which hosts the share.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Let me see if I got this straight:
Network A (Domain) -------VPN-----> Network B (Workgroup)
Network A: user1@domain, user2@domain, etc
Network B: Computer1: localuser1, localuser2. Computer2:localuser1, localuser2
If, for example, user1@domain would like to access a network share on computer2 on Network B, he will have to connect using (again, for example) localuser2 credentials.
Am I right?

Comment: More or less, yes because Computer2 has no knowledge of the users or passwords in Network A's domain.  When not in a domain, it can only validate its own local users/passwords.